# Failed close audit and I don't understand why

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10383991) (I voted to close it). Here's [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961893/how-to-create-posts-by-month-and-year-table-in-jekyll-without-plugins). Frankly I don't understand why this should be a good question. It's basically a short description of the problem with "give me teh codez". This could be closed as *too broad* or *off-topic -> mcve missing* but I really don't think it's a good question and feasible as an audit question.

//edit: Okay, now the question is heavily downvoted and closed, so this won't happen again.

Comment: If its any consolation, thanks to the meta effect the question and answer both got a fair number of downvotes, making them inelligible to be an audit anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question isn't good. It's a tool/code request.

The problem here is that it's been posted in a relatively low-traffic tag, it's gotten a few upvotes (**Sigh**), and an accepted, upvoted answer.

This causes the system to think it's a good question.
Basically, this is an audit you can only pass by picking the wrong action. It is also a perfect example of why an automated system to chose questions as audits is flawed.
<sub>(Not that I can think of a better alternative though.)</sub>

Comment: The question reads: give me codez, and a 10k+ user complied incredibly willingly. I feel sorry for the audit system here.